# C++ Calculator Operator

Tags: c++, computer-science

I've got a problem with my code, each time that I put something else other than the operator (+,/,*,-) it will still ask for numbers. I want it to stop and show the text "Error! operator is not correct" when someone will put other things than the operator

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char op;
    float num1, num2;
    cout << "Enter operator either + or - or * or /: ";
    cin >> op;
    cout << "Enter the first operand: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter the second operand: ";
    cin >> num2;

    switch (op)
    {

    case '+':
        cout << num1 + num2;
        break;
    case '-':
        cout << num1 - num2;
        break;
    case '*':
        cout << num1 * num2;
        break;
    case '/':
        cout << num1 / num2;
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Error! operator is not correct";
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Many Thanks In Advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuaPU.png)

Comment: It's behaving exactly as you coded it - prompt for and read a character, then prompt for and read two integers, and ONLY then check the value of `op`.    You need to check `op` immediately after reading it, and before prompting for and reading the subsequent integral values.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're wanting the input cleared?

If you want certain inputs to be rejected, then after an input, you need to clear the standard input.

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
```

Don't forget to ask for input again after doing this, or nothing will happen. 
Consider putting it in a while loop and looping through:

- Ask for operator
- If an operator, ask for a number
- Else clear the input and ask for the operator again

Hope this helps!

Comment: In addition, `if (!(cin >> op))` will tell you if you need to clean theoutput or not.

Comment: Too bad this doesn't answer the question as asked.     The OP is asking why there is no error message emitted on entering a wrong character, and before reading the integral values.

Comment: This is not the answer that the OP looking for

Answer (score 0):

You put the `cin` input operation at the wrong place. If you want your code to output error immediately after you input the wrong operator, you have to move the `cin` part after checking the operator  or early exit the program when you meet the unidentified operator.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void askNum(float &num1, float &num2)  //passing the values by reference 
{
    cout << "Enter the first operand: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter the second operand: ";
    cin >> num2;
}

int main()
{
    char op;
    float num1, num2;
    cout << "Enter operator either + or - or * or /: ";
    cin >> op;

    switch (op)
    {
        case '+':
            askNum(num1, num2);
            cout << num1 + num2;
            break;
        case '-':
            askNum(num1, num2);
            cout << num1 - num2;
            break;
        case '*':
            askNum(num1, num2);
            cout << num1 * num2;
            break;
        case '/':
            askNum(num1, num2);
            cout << num1 / num2;
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Error! operator is not correct";
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

or using your code, but add `return 0` like this : **(It works but I don't recommend this)**

```
default:
    cout << "Error! operator is not correct";
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to try this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

unordered_map < char,function < float (float, float) >>
  op_mapper{
  {'+', std::plus < float >()},
  {'-', std::minus < float >()},
  {'*', std::multiplies < float >()},
  {'/', std::divides < float >()}};
int main ()
{
  char op;
  float num1,num2;
  while (op != 'q') {
      cout << "Enter operator either + or - or * or /: ";
      cin >> op;

      if (op_mapper.find (op) != op_mapper.end ()) {
      cout << "Enter the first operand: ";
      cin >> num1;
      cout << "Enter the second operand: ";
      cin >> num2;
      cout << op_mapper[op] (num1, num2) << endl;
    } else {
      cout << "Error! operator is not correct";
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After read the operator you need check whether operator is correct or not. Below code is solved your problem.

> code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char op;
    float num1, num2;
    cout << "Enter operator either + or - or * or /: ";
    cin >> op;

    if(op == '+' || op == '-'|| op == '*'|| op == '/'){
        cout << "Enter the first operand: ";
        cin >> num1;
        cout << "Enter the second operand: ";
        cin >> num2;    

    }else{
        cout << "Error! operator is not correct";
        return 0 ;
    }

    switch (op)
    {
        case '+':
            cout << num1 + num2;
            break;
        case '-':
            cout << num1 - num2;
            break;
        case '*':
            cout << num1 * num2;
            break;
        case '/':
            cout << num1 / num2;
            break;
    }    

    return 0;
}
```